# mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/dev/shm’: Read-only file system

Tags: git, github

Salutations!

I have recently been getting the warnings below every time I open Git Bash or Command Prompt.

I have tried to follow the solution at https://github.community/t/mkdir-cannot-create-directory-dev-shm-read-only-file-system/12190 which mentions my problem specifically but I do not have the specific Git Bash shortcut at all.

git push was also not working temporarily even though my SSH credentials were still there but that issue seems to have solved itself.

I am unsure of what this issue even is and if I should do something about it.

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/dev/shm’: Read-only file system

Creating /dev/shm directory failed.
POSIX semaphores and POSIX shared memory will not work

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/dev/mqueue’: Read-only file system

Creating /dev/mqueue directory failed.
POSIX message queues will not work

ln: failed to create symbolic link '/dev/stdin': Read-only file system
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/dev/stdout': Read-only file system
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/dev/stderr': Read-only file system
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/dev/fd': Read-only file system
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/etc/mtab': Permission denied
'C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts' -> '/etc/hosts'
/usr/bin/cp: cannot create regular file '/etc/hosts': Permission denied
'C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\protocol' -> '/etc/protocols'
/usr/bin/cp: cannot create regular file '/etc/protocols': Permission denied
'C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\services' -> '/etc/services'
/usr/bin/cp: cannot create regular file '/etc/services': Permission denied
'C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\networks' -> '/etc/networks'
/usr/bin/cp: cannot create regular file '/etc/networks': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a CMD, type `set HOME`, and check that:

- `HOMEDRIVE=C:`
- `HOMEPATH=\Users\<you>`

Make sure to use the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)

Then, for testing, set a simplified `PATH`, with:

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set PATH=C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core;%PATH%
```

In that same CMD, type `bash`, and see if the issue persists.